# How to get the length of Property?

Tags: .net, entity-framework-5

I am using Entity Framework code First Approach so I have the mapping model like shown below.Like this I have 40 models Now I want to know the length of column such as BC_ID   as shown above programmatically.How can I get max column Length ?I think we can do it using Reflection class but do not know exactly how to do it.I am using Entity Framework 5.0

```
public class BusinessContactMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<BusinessContact>
    {
        public BusinessContactMap()
        {
            // Primary Key
            this.HasKey(t => t.BC_ID);

            // Properties
            this.Property(t => t.BC_ID)
                .IsRequired()
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.BC_FirstName)
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.BC_LastName)
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.BC_Mobile)
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.BC_Office)
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            this.Property(t => t.BC_Mail)
                .HasMaxLength(64);

            // Table & Column Mappings
            this.ToTable("BusinessContacts");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_ID).HasColumnName("BC_ID");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_FirstName).HasColumnName("BC_FirstName");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_LastName).HasColumnName("BC_LastName");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_Mobile).HasColumnName("BC_Mobile");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_Office).HasColumnName("BC_Office");
            this.Property(t => t.BC_Mail).HasColumnName("BC_Mail");
            this.Property(t => t.Record_Instance).HasColumnName("Record_Instance");
            this.Property(t =>t.Record_LastModified).HasColumnName("Record_LastModified");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2546267/115578