# Get Data Length with Entity Framework (to validate data lengths on a WCF Service)

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
create table #Employee (
    EmployeeId int identity(1,1) not null,
    FirstName varchar(100) not null,
    LastName varchar(100) not null,
    Suffix varchar(10) not null,
    Prefix  varchar(10) not null,
    Address varchar(500) null)
```

And I fill this table with a WCF (Soap) service.  My data contract looks like this:

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Suffix { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Prefix { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public virtual string Address { get; set; }
}
```

The contract has `String` for all of these fields.  A [string can be a max of about 1,073,741,823 chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string).  That is well over the limits that the database will allow.  When a client sends up data they can put in really really long values into my contract.

I would like to find this out before I attempt (and fail) an insert.

I have a very nice in-house made validation framework that will send a Fault down to the client.  And I could go and put in a validation for each item.  But if I hardcode the lengths of the fields then I see it spiraling out of control very very fast.  (If the length of a column has to be changed in two spots, then I am opening up the way for bugs when only one or the other gets changed.)

Is there a way (with entity framework) to get the lengths of a data item?  So I can validate it prior to trying to persist it?

Or is there another way to do this validation (except by just failing the insert).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MetadataWorkspace and handle the SavingChanges event on your ObjectContext.

[Field max length in Entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/748939/field-max-length-in-entity-framework)