# entity framework 5 MaxLength

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

I was using EF4 and a piece of code I found to get the `MaxLength` value from an entity like this:

```
public static int? GetMaxLength(string entityTypeName, string columnName)
        {
            int? result = null;
            using (fooEntities context = new fooEntities())
            {
                Type entType = Type.GetType(entityTypeName);
                var q = from meta in context.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                                  .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                        from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                        .Where(p => p.Name == columnName
                                    && p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name == "String")
                        select p;

                var queryResult = q.Where(p =>
                {
                    bool match = p.DeclaringType.Name == entityTypeName;
                    if (!match && entType != null)
                    {
                        match = entType.Name == p.DeclaringType.Name;
                    }

                    return match;

                }).Select(sel => sel.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value);
                if (queryResult.Any())
                {
                    result = Convert.ToInt32(queryResult.First());
                }

                return result;
            }
        }
```

However, I upgraded to EF5 and I know get this error message:

```
...fooEntities'  does not contain a definition for 'MetadataWorkspace' and no
extension method 'MetadataWorkspace' accepting a first argument of type
'...fooEntities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
 reference?)
```

What's the best way to get that meta data from EF5?

Comment: I have had all kinds of problems with EF5 relating assemby references. Have you tried to uninstall and install EF5 again using the package manager console? That has solved some of my problems earlier. Make sure to do this for all your projects in the solution. Might be worth a try.

Comment: this is a fresh install of VS2012 and a fresh project. I'm bring in code from an older project

Comment: Note: It doesn't bring `MaxLength` value of a column *from* Database. If you don't annotate the length in your model's property, for eg: `[Column("SomeColumn", TypeName="varchar(10)")]`, this code simply returns Max for `property.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value`, which makes it run into Cast exception. If you want the length, i.e. `10` in this case directly from the database, checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330103/8644294

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It means that you have not only upgraded EF but you have also changes the API. There are two APIs - the core ObjectContext API and simplified DbContext API. Your code is dependent on ObjectContext API (the only API available in EF4) but EF5 uses DbContext API (added in separate EntityFramework.dll assembly since EF4.1). If you want to use new EF features and your previous code you should just upgrade to .NET 4.5.

If you also want to use a new API you will have to update a lot of your existing code but it is still possible to get `ObjectContext` from `DbContext` and make your method work again. You just need to use this snippet:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
```

and use `objectContext` instead of `context` in your code.

Comment: Yes I should have made that more clear. I created a new project to upgrade to the "new hotness". I made the change but I'm getting the error `Project.Model.fooEntities is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I incorrectly wrote the example. Check the corrected version.

Comment: this solved **that** error but now I'm getting an unrelated error. *sigh* :) thanks

Answer (score 30):

This is a very handy piece of code. I refactored it a bit and it's so useful I thought I would post it here.

```
public static int? GetMaxLength<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> column)
    {
        int? result = null;
        using (var context = new EfContext())
        {
            var entType = typeof(T);
            var columnName = ((MemberExpression) column.Body).Member.Name;

            var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) context).ObjectContext;
            var test = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace);

            if(test == null)
                return null;

            var q = test
                .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                .SelectMany(meta => ((EntityType) meta).Properties
                .Where(p => p.Name == columnName && p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name == "String"));

            var queryResult = q.Where(p =>
                                          {
                                              var match = p.DeclaringType.Name == entType.Name;
                                              if (!match)
                                                  match = entType.Name == p.DeclaringType.Name;

                                              return match;

                                          })
                .Select(sel => sel.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value)
                .ToList();

            if (queryResult.Any())
                result = Convert.ToInt32(queryResult.First());

            return result;
        }
    }
```

And you can call it like:

```
GetMaxLength<Customer>(x => x.CustomerName);
```

This is assuming you've got a DbSet defined in your DbContext of type Customer, which has a property of CustomerName with a defined MaxLength.

This is very helpful for things like creating Model attributes that set a textbox's maxlength to the max length of the field in the database, always ensuring the two are the same.

Comment: What is EFContext? If it is your app. specific generated class, you should pass it as a parameter, not make it embedded in static function- see IOC.

Comment: Dude u rock u, I just spent an hour on this and could not figure out how to run it. Your codes works almost directly just remember to check ur context this is awesome

Comment: Works perfectly! I changed it to throw an exception instead of returning null.

Comment: I had to include: System.Linq, System.Linq.Expressions, System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure and System.Data.Metadata.Edm. Added this to the abstract ancestor controller in my MVC app, and it does the job nicely.

Comment: Also made it throw exception instead of returning null, and instead of calling EfContext() I'm instead passing in the DbContext from the caller. Method signature looks like this: protected static int GetMaxColumnLength<T>(DbContext db, Expression<Func<T, string>> column)

Comment: Note: It doesn't bring `MaxLength` value of a column *from* Database. If you don't annotate the length in your model's property, for eg: `[Column("SomeColumn", TypeName="varchar(10)")]`, this code simply returns Max for `property.TypeUsage.Facets["MaxLength"].Value`, which makes it run into Cast exception. If you want the length, i.e. `10` in this case directly from the database, checkout my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71330103/8644294

Answer (score 11):

I refactored mccow002's example into a copy-paste-ready Extension method class:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Metadata.Edm;

public static class DbContextExtensions
{

    // get MaxLength as an extension method to the DbContext
    public static int? GetMaxLength<T>(this DbContext context, Expression<Func<T, string>> column)
    {
        return (int?)context.GetFacets<T>(column)["MaxLength"].Value;
    }

    // get MaxLength as an extension method to the Facets (I think the extension belongs here)
    public static int? GetMaxLength(this ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<Facet> facets)
    {
        return (int?)facets["MaxLength"].Value;            
    }

    // just for fun: get all the facet values as a Dictionary 
    public static Dictionary<string,object> AsDictionary(this ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<Facet> facets) {
        return facets.ToDictionary(o=>o.Name,o=>o.Value);
    }


    public static ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<Facet> GetFacets<T>(this DbContext context, Expression<Func<T, string>> column)
    {
        ReadOnlyMetadataCollection<Facet> result = null;

        var entType = typeof(T);
        var columnName = ((MemberExpression)column.Body).Member.Name;

        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
        var test = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace);

        if (test == null)
            return null;

        var q = test
            .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
            .SelectMany(meta => ((EntityType)meta).Properties
            .Where(p => p.Name == columnName && p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name == "String"));

        var queryResult = q.Where(p =>
        {
            var match = p.DeclaringType.Name == entType.Name;
            if (!match)
                match = entType.Name == p.DeclaringType.Name;

            return match;

        })
            .Select(sel => sel)
            .FirstOrDefault();

        result = queryResult.TypeUsage.Facets;

        return result;

    }

}
```

Comment: The `.Select(sel => sel)` at the bottom doesn't do anything, does it?  I took it out and it seems not to care.

Comment: You are correct, in this instance, no the `Select` does not do anything. But that's just because the lambda expression is returning it's own input parameter. Had it been something like `.Select(sel => sel.SomeProperty)`, then it deleting the `Select` would have returned a different `result`.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue and solution is here;

```
  MyDBEntities ctx = new MyDBEntities();
        var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;

        var cols = from meta in objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace)
                   .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
                   from p in (meta as EntityType).Properties
                      .Where(p => p.DeclaringType.Name == "TableName")
                   select new
                   {
                       PropertyName = p.Name                          
                   };
```