# Entity Framework 6 - Getting the field size

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I need to grab the field size of a column in a model using Entity Framework 6 (the model was defined in the database and the field size is not known at run-time).

I see some sample code for EF4/5 here:

[entity framework 5 MaxLength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12378186/entity-framework-5-maxlength#)

But unfortunately, this code is broken in EF6:

```
 var test = objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems(DataSpace.CSpace);

        if(test == null)
            return null;

        var q = test
            .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.EntityType)
            .SelectMany(meta => ((EntityType) meta).Properties
            .Where(p => p.Name == columnName && p.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name == "String"));
```

Reason for this being that objectContext.MetadataWorkspace.GetItems no longer seems to return the same collection type as before, so you can't just search through the collection set in the same way using the 'where' method etc.

Has anybody any ideas of how to tackle this problem in EF6?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Did you check the version of Linq that you're using? Did you also check the Debug run time Values of test from EF 4/5 which differs from EF 6?

Comment: You got me on the right lines. Problem was, I had using System.Linq.Expressions but not using System.Linq; School boy error really... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem was down to my using/includes. These are required:

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Linq;
using System;
```